# Ошибка SyntaxError при x \ y в коде

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите исправить ошибку.

```
  File "C:\...\TEST.py", line 12
(x \ y)
      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Вот сам код

```
Work = True

while Work:
double = ""
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
if x == 1:
    print(double)
    break
elif x % y == 0:
    double += "0"
    (x \ y)
else:
    double += "1"
    if x % y == 0:
        (x \ y)
    else:
        x-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

переверните слеш в обратную сторону)